# D3 Scaling issue of Graph with appropriate scaling of Scales(Y-axis,X-axis)

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, visualization

[Example Code Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahir_pucit_7/we7mmvk5/12/)

I am working on a heatmap. In which I make the rectangles of heat map (width,height) programmatically depending upon data.

I want to add sliders for zooming on X-axis(time range) , Y-axis(distance range).
I tried d3 scaling options which works fine. But the scales(x-axis, y-axis) don't scale in proportion to rectangles of graph. Like if a rectangle was between 10,20 miles y-axis scale. it goes further than 20 miles on scaling.

Then I tried viewbox on svg. It works . Scales are kept in proportion to graph exactly.

**I want to keep the proportion of scales and graph on scaling  but not want to increase the size of scales labels as it makes the graph ugly.**

Here is code snippet for how I am making my graph initially

```
d3.json('dateWiseNewDataRight.json',function(err,right_dat){
            // console.log(right_dat);
            var dateGroups=_.groupBy(right_dat, "DATE");
            var data = [];
            var x= 0,y=0;
            var tlength=0;
            var totalDates=Object.keys(dateGroups);
            var graphWidth=(total_width/totalDates.length)-6;

            for(var key in dateGroups){
                tlength=0;
                data = [];
                y=0;
                var segmentMiles=0;
                var currentGraphData=dateGroups[key];
                var road=currentGraphData[0]['ROAD'];
                for(var i = 0; i < currentGraphData.length-1; i++) {
                    tlength+=currentGraphData[i].MILES;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < currentGraphData.length-1; i++) {
                    var height=0;
                    segmentMiles=segmentMiles+currentGraphData[i].MILES;
                    for(var j in times){
                        if(road!=currentGraphData[i]['ROAD']){
                            road=currentGraphData[i]['ROAD'];
                            height=1;
                            for(var k=0;k<times.length;k++){
                                data.push({value:20000,x:x,y:y, height:height ,width:col_width,name:"",tmc:"", length:"",road:""});
                                x=x+col_width;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        else{

                            col_width=graphWidth/24;
                            var Congestion= currentGraphData[i][times[j]];
                            height=(currentGraphData[i].MILES/tlength)*total_height;
                            //road=leftDat[i]['ROAD'];
                            data.push({value:Congestion,x:x,y:y, height:height ,width:col_width,name:currentGraphData[i]['NAME'],tmc:currentGraphData[i]['TMC CODE'], length:currentGraphData[i]['MILES'],road:currentGraphData[i]['ROAD'],miles:segmentMiles});
                            // x=x+col_width;
                        }
                        x=x+col_width;
                    }
                    y=y+height;
                    x=0;
                }

                plotSegmentNames(panelData);

                var margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 10, left: 10 };

                $('.heat-map-2').append('<div class="chart-right-'+key+' " style="width: '+graphWidth+'px;float:left;margin:3px;;overflow:hidden"></div>');
                var graphDiv='.chart-right-'+key;
                var right_Svg = d3.select(graphDiv)
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("class", "chart")
                        .attr("width",graphWidth)
                        .attr("height", total_height )
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                var right_color_chart = right_Svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "rightHeatMap");
                right_color_chart.call(tip);

                var color = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([d3.min(data), 1])
                        .range(["blue", "green"]);
                right_color_chart.selectAll("rect")
                        .data(data)
                        .enter()
                        .append("rect")
                        .attr("x", function(d,i) {return d.x; })
                        .attr("y", function(d,i) { return d.y; })
                        .attr("width", col_width)
                        .attr("height",  function(d) { return d.height; })
                        .attr("road",function(d){
                            return d.road;
                        })
                        .attr("miles",  function(d) { return d.miles; })
                        .style("fill", function(d) {return chooseColor(d.value);})
                        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
                var   right_xAxisScale = d3.time.scale(),
                        right_xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                .orient('bottom')
                                .ticks(d3.time.hour,1)
                                .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%I %p'))
                                .tickSubdivide(6);

                right_xAxis.scale(right_xAxisScale.range([0,graphWidth]).domain([timeFormat.parse(times[0]),timeFormat.parse(times[times.length-1])]));
                right_Svg.append('g')
                        .attr('class','x axis')
                        .call(right_xAxis)
                        .append('text')
                        .attr('transform','translate('+total_width+',0)');

                var    yAxisScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                .range([0,xAxisHeight])
                                .domain([0,tlength]),
                        yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                .orient('right')
                                .ticks(5)
                                .scale(yAxisScale);
                right_Svg.append('g')
                        .attr('transform','translate('+1+','+0+')')
                        .attr('class','y axis')
                        .call(yAxis)
//                        .append('text')
//                        .text('Length')
//                        .attr('transform','translate(100,'+total_height+') rotate(-90)');
            }



            var   testTimes =times;
            var distanceRange=[0,60];
            $("#scale-slider")
                    .slider({

                        animate:true,
                        range: true,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 1440,
                        step: 24,
                        values: [0, 1440],
                        slide: function (e, ui) {
                            var sliderTime= calculateSiderTime(e,ui);
                            testTimes=[sliderTime.nob1Time,sliderTime.nob2Time];
                            $('.x.axis').remove();
                            $('.y.axis').remove();
                          /*  redrawHeatMaps('left',left_color_chart,'leftHeatMap',leftDat,testTimes,tlength);
                            redrawHeatMaps('right',right_color_chart,'rightHeatMap',right_dat,testTimes,tlength);*/

                            redrawYHeatMaps('left',left_color_chart,'leftHeatMap',leftDat,testTimes,tlength,distanceRange);
                            redrawYHeatMaps('right',right_color_chart,'rightHeatMap',right_dat,testTimes,tlength,distanceRange);

                        }
                    })
                    .on("slidechange", function( e, ui ) {


                    });

            $("#distance-slider")
                    .slider({

                        animate:true,
                        range: true,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 60,
                        step: 5,
                        values: [0, 60],
                        slide: function (e, ui) {
                            distanceRange=ui.values;
                            $('.x.axis').remove();
                            $('.y.axis').remove();
                         //   left_color_chart.attr("transform", "translate("+ d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
                            redrawYHeatMaps('left',left_color_chart,'leftHeatMap',leftDat,testTimes,tlength,distanceRange);
                            redrawYHeatMaps('right',right_color_chart,'rightHeatMap',right_dat,testTimes,tlength,distanceRange);
                            $('.slider-distance1').html(ui.values[0]);
                            $('.slider-distance2').html( ui.values[1]);
                        }
                    })
                    .on("slidechange", function( e, ui ) {


                    });
        });
```

Comment: Please add a working example, If possible.

Comment: @FrancisHemsher [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahir_pucit_7/we7mmvk5/12/) is here now

Comment: @Achilles If I've understood exactly, Your problem is y-axis and heatmap rects not equally scale and you want to scale y-axis equally according to heatmap rects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just only edit `yAxisScale`'s domain when scale event is occurred.

[Here is updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/we7mmvk5/13/)

First, remove `y` method in `zoom`. It helps auto-scaling for an axis but, it is not your case. I'll give an explanation at last.

```
zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0, 5])
  .scale(1)
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

After, adjust `yAxisScale` domain when scale value is changed.

```
function zoomed() {
  yAxisScale.domain([0, tlength / d3.event.scale]); // added
  leftSvg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
  zoomIn();
}
```

Why use division not multiplication? Because if you scale twice, axis values only shown up a half in comparison with its original values.

If you use `zoom`'s `y` method, it is going to auto-scale `yAxisScale` using multiplication. So, I said it is not your case above.

Comment: Thanks it is working perfectly. Can you explain how you come up with the idea that on scaling we have to divide tlength with d3.event.scale . to get appropriate yScale

Comment: If I want to manually set scale value . Like using a slider I only want to display data between 20 to 40 on Y-axis. Can I do that?

Comment: Let's assume that the distance range is between 0 and 40. If you scale rects of heatmap twice, `d3.event.scale` will be `2.0` and the range have to be shown up a half (0 - 20).

Comment: You should group heatmap rects and just translate them to make them slide.

Comment: Yes the zoom is from 0 to some value. If I want to zoom in between 20 to 25 or 30 to 40 . Some range in the middle. What should I do then and how? Thanks

Comment: At the end I want to use a slider . So when I move knobs of slider I get the appropriate zoom. on distance range selected.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you may want to zoom, via mousewheel,  into the heatmap cells with the axis not scaling.
Here are a few suggestions. Give them a try.

1) Change zoom behavior to:

```
              zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0,5]).scale(1).on("zoom", zoomIn);
```

2) Remove the zoomed function and change the zoomIn:

```
function zoomIn(){
var t = d3.event.translate,
s = d3.event.scale;
left_color_chart.attr("transform","translate("+t+")scale("+s+")")
}
```

Comment: Its actually doing the same behviour what my code does. Graph is scaling but the axis are not changing according to scale proportion. Specifically ,I only want the scaling of Y -axis.

Comment: Someone just posted a fiddle that may help see: https://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/u6rj20jc/1/ (This came in from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544216/d3-version-4-zoom-behaviour-on-g-element )